# DDS 9th topic causes a crash

Tags: publish-subscribe, qos, data-distribution-service

I am using `DDS` (more specifically `RTI DDS`) for a `java` application. I am creating each `topic` for my `DDS` implementation one by one in code so thus I can test each one with a `DDS spy` after the code is written. When I wrote the 8th `topic` everything worked fine. However when I then wrote the 9th `topic`, nothing seemed to happen as the program seemed to stop somewhere. I then debugged and after a lot of stepping into code, got this printed to council.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x01349a58, pid=16109, tid=2429123440
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b17) (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x48aa58]  java_lang_String::utf8_length(oopDesc*)+0x58
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/foo/core or core.16109
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# 
# /home/foo/corehs_err_pid16109.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
[D0000|ENABLE]COMMENDSrReaderService_new:!create worker-specific object
[D0000|ENABLE]PRESPsService_enable:!create srr (strict reliable reader)
[D0000|ENABLE]DDS_DomainParticipantService_enable:!enable publish/subscribe service
[D0000|ENABLE]DDS_DomainParticipant_enableI:!enable service
```

I am not sure why this has happened all of a sudden when I created my 9th `topic`, yet if I only have 8 it works great. I have tried to increase my `resourcelimits` as well and get an `Immutable QOS Policy` error. Does anyone know why this error is occurring in terms of why my 9th `topic` causes a failure and how to fix the problem? I am running my application on `32 bit RHEL 6.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found on this is because of the `max objects per thread` by default is set to 8 by the `qos`. To change this setting, before your first topic is created you must do the following.

```
    DomainParticipantFactoryQos factoryQos = 
            new DomainParticipantFactoryQos();
    DomainParticipantFactory.TheParticipantFactory.get_qos(factoryQos);
    factoryQos.resource_limits.max_objects_per_thread = 2048;
    DomainParticipantFactory.TheParticipantFactory.set_qos(factoryQos);
```

This then sets the size before the DDS starts and is thus editable and not immutable at that point.